# Function of Activation functions

Tags: python, pytorch, activation-function

is it possible to define a function of activation function? I tried to do :

```
def activation():
    # return nn.Sin()
    # return nn.Tanh()
    # return nn.Sigmoid()
    # return nn.Tanhshrink()
    return nn.HardTanh(-1,1)
    # return nn.Hardswish()
    # return nn.functionnal.silu()
```

But i get an error when trying to call it. Here is an example:

```
def f():
  return nn.Tanh()
input = torch.randn(2)
output = f(input)
print(output)
```

it outputs "TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given". It doesn't work even i gave it an argument x.

Comment: it's unclear what you are trying to achieve. `f = nn.Tanh`?

Comment: yes so it's  ```def f():
  return nn.Tanh()
input = torch.randn(2)
output = f()(input)
print(output)``` because f return an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the object-oriented approach:

```
>>> f = nn.Tanh()
>>> output = f(x)
```

Or the functional approach where you will find the equivalent for [`nn.Tanh`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Tanh.html) inside [`nn.functional`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html) as [`tanh`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.tanh.html#torch.nn.functional.tanh).

```
>>> f = nn.functional.tanh
>>> output = f(x)
```

Comment: Alternatively (but uselessly), OP could use the code they have now but call with `f()(input)`.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you are not providing argument to the function. Is this what you are trying to do?

```py
def f(x):
  return nn.Tanh(x)
```

Comment: it doesn't work like that because f return an object

Comment: I fixeed it with ```def f():
  return nn.Tanh()
input = torch.randn(2)
output = f()(input)
print(output)```